# how to show maxHeight and Min height to controls of android page?

Tags: android, android-layout

as i am new to android i want to fix max height/width and min height/width to my layout and its controls
i tried using

```
 android:minWidth="75dp"
android:maxWidth="75dp"
android:minHeight="30dp"     
android:maxHeight="30dp"
```

also using android:stretchColumns="*" for table layout

but output on emulator of tab/ or any other bigger screen its not showing any effect.its not working properly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:maxHeight="30dp"
android:maxWidth="75dp"
android:minHeight="30dp"
android:minWidth="75dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".AirSalesActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/roundshape"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <!-- Lable Area -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwspnLbl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="1dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblCust"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/lblCust"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblPros"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/lblPros"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- Spinner Area -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwspn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="1dip" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnAECust"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:hint="@string/SelectCust"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnAEProspect"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:hint="@string/SelectProspect"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- Text Area -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwEditTxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblCommo"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/lblCommo"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <!-- For alignment Purpose Dummy -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblCommo1"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:text="@string/strNull"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwCommSpn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnAEComodity"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtAESplNt"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:hint="@string/txtSplNt"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- Air Label -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwAir"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblFrm"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/lblFrm"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTo"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/lblTo"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
        <!-- Air Ports -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwAir1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnAEFrmPort"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnAEToPort"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- Air Weight Section -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwAEWt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtAEWt"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:hint="@string/txtWt"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtAEVol"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:hint="@string/txtVol"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- Cargo Date Section -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwlblCar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblCargo"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/lblCargo"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblNoOfPack"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/lblNoOfPack"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwCargoDt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblAEDate"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/strNull"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtAENoOfPack"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:hint="@string/txtNoOfPack"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>
        <!-- Submit Button Section -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwOESubmit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAESubmit"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:height="10dp"
                android:text="@string/submit"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:width="75dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

please help me to make it possible

Comment: what is the need to give max height for the parent?

Comment: i have also tried to give max height/width to controls individually..but not working due to android:stretchColumns="*" want to keep fix spread/shrink for controls even if size of mobile resolution increase or decrease

Comment: You need not specify the dp values to render a view properly in different screen densities. You can just use fill_parent which would serve the purpose.

Comment: you have given 30dp and 75dp as width and height for all the screens. so it is going to show the same size in all the screen sizes. use generic valaues to get better views like fill_parent match_parent wrap_content like this

Comment: Refer to this link ... It tells you how to specify size conditions for imageview ... You can try the same for your layout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914810/how-to-set-both-min-and-max-size-for-an-imageview-in-android Hope it helps